# Запрос из parse.com в AsyncTask

Tags: android, parse.com

**То что пользователь вводит в ma_number_group сравнивается в parse.com и если есть совпадение - переменной e_err == true, иначе false. Подскажите, где я ошибаюсь. Потому что даже если нет совпадений в БД, e_err все равно присваивается true.** *Спасибо за помощь!*

public class MainA extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Snackbar snackbar;
EditText ma_number_group;
ProgressBar pb;
Button ma_search;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

String modified_number;
Boolean e_err;
Boolean oshubka;

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDrawer);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_a);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
    pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    ma_number_group = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ma_number_group);
    ma_search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ma_search);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);


    ma_number_group.setFocusable(false);

    ma_number_group.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ma_number_group.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

    ma_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new MyTask().execute();

        }

    });

}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

        modified_number = ma_number_group
                .getText()
                .toString()
                .toUpperCase()
                .replaceAll(" ", "")
                .replaceAll("-", "")
                .replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "")
                .trim();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Schedule");
        query.whereEqualTo("NumberGroup", modified_number);
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {

                    e_err = true;

                } else {

                    e_err= false;

                }
            }
        });

        return e_err;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        ma_number_group = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ma_number_group);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);



        if (isOnline() == true) {
            if (ma_number_group.getText().length() == 0) {
                snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(relativeLayout, (getResources().getString(R.string.error_number_group)), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toast_red));
                snackbar.show();
            } else {

                if (e_err) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainA.this, ScheduleA.class);
                    intent.putExtra("NumberGroup", modified_number);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(relativeLayout, (getResources().getString(R.string.error_number_group_not_found)), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                    View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
                    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toast_red));
                    snackbar.setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.create_group), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainA.this, CreateGroupA.class);
                            intent.putExtra("NumberGroup", modified_number);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }).show();
                }

                ma_number_group.getText().clear();
            }
        } else {
            snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(relativeLayout, (getResources().getString(R.string.error_internet)), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
            snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toast_red));
            snackbar.show();
        }

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Вывод у меня пока только один: `ParseException e` не `null`

Answer (score 1):

В общем так, из этого запроса true получается только если 2 раза нажимать на ma_search (кнопка), также и с false.  Не могу понять почему?

query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {

```
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                e_err = true;

            } else {

                e_err= false;

            }
        }
    });
```